# JPA/Hibernate JpaSystemException: identifier of an instance of X was altered from Y to Z

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, java-17

I'm updating my Spring Boot application from Java 11 to Java 17, and Spring Boot `2.7.18` to `3.2.4`, and running the tests I'm getting an error.

So, I have a entity called `WorkloadDAO` like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workloads")
@IdClass(WorkloadId.class)
public class WorkloadDAO {

  @Id
  @NonNull()
  private String id;
  
  @Id
  @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  // more attributes

  @PrePersist
  protected void onCreate() {
    createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
  }
```

The `createdAt` attribute will always be received with null value, and it will be set by the `onCreate()` method annotated with `@PrePersist` before save the instance in the database.

As you can see in the annotation `@IdClass(WorkloadId.class)`, I'm setting `WorkloadId` as the id of this class. The `WorkloadId` class is like this:

```
public class WorkloadId implements Serializable {

  private String id;
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;
}
```

So far, so good until the test.
For example, I'm running this test:

```
  @Test
  void testSaveWorkload() {
    String id = "someid";
    WorkloadDAO dao = WorkloadDAO.builder()
        .id(id)
        .build();

    WorkloadDAO response = repository.saveAndFlush(dao);

    assertThat(repository.findById(WorkloadId.builder()
            .id(id)
            .createdAt(response.getCreatedAt())
            .build()))
        .get()
        .extracting("createdAt").isNotNull();
  }
```

Before updating Java and Spring Boot, this test was running successfully. But now, I'm getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: identifier of an instance of com.adevinta.delivery.workloadapi.data.WorkloadDAO was altered from WorkloadId(id=someid, createdAt=2024-03-28T12:26:34.355098) to WorkloadId(id=someid, createdAt=null)
```

Can you help me to understand why I'm getting this?
Thanks!

What I expect to happen is the test works, without setting the field `createdAt` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is due to the `insertable = false` attribute on createdAt. The value assigned in `@PrePersist` will not be saved to the database as a result. Typically 'created at' fields are insertable but not updatable and visa versa for 'modified at' fields. Try changing the createdAt column definition to:

`@Column(name = "created_at", insertable = true, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")`.